# How to display html content in block in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal-6, block

How can i  display external(from server) html content into block region.

let me tell you what i did so far is i created a new block on my site called sitemap and put some php code

```
<?php include('../sitemap/sitemap.html'); ?>
```

and set this block region to footer.

But it show nothing so plz help me so i do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the include file path is wrong. For better results, you can put that file in the themes folder and call it.

```
<?php include(path_to_theme().'/sitemap.html'); ?>
```